# How does this MySQL statement work?

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `myDB`.`usersystem` (
`userid` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
`username` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL , 
`password` VARCHAR( 32 ) NOT NULL , 
`email` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL , 
PRIMARY KEY ( `userid` )
);
```

Sorry, I would search but I have no idea how to search for such a specific misunderstanding.

I'm starting to learn MySQL, and I'm getting comfortable, but I'm confused what the backticks do, and why when the table was created it has a period between them. What does usersystem denote?

Comment: Backticks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962859/importance-of-backtick-around-table-name-in-mysql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the stuff you don't understand could be removed without changing the meaning of this statement!

The backticks are just for quoting; they're optional, but they distinguish between a keyword and the name of a table or column. If you wanted a table named `SELECT`, putting the table name in quotes like this would let you create one.

Backticks are used for quoting identifiers by default, but there's a special ANSI_QUOTES mode that, if activated, lets you use double-quote characters for this instead. Single quotes are used for quoting character strings.

`myDB.usersystem` refers to a table named `usersystem` in the database named `myDB`. Naming the database is optional, as it defaults to the connected one. You can also set the implicit database by using the `use` command, as in "`use myDB`".

Comment: Oh okay, so two questions if I could! 1. Are backticks interchangeable with ' and "? 2. Could I get rid of the `myDB.` part by typing `use myDB;` beforehand?

Answer (score 1):

Backkticks prevent names from being interpreted as SQL keywords so you can create table names like `create` or `date`.

The dot separates the schema name from the table name.

Schemas allow you to have identically named tables for different purposes, such as a users table in N different applications.

Answer (score 1):

usersystem is the table name, myDB is the database name.

`<database name>`.`<table name>` is the fully qualified way to reference a table.

The back ticks are used to denote the name of the resource. They are not always necessary but it is a good practice to use them.