# How to find rows in a table that are not in other table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables:

1. `staticip` has two columns: `ip`, `staticipid`
2. `rm_users` has many columns and one of it is `staticipcpe`

I would like to find rows in `staticip` table that is `staticipid='2'` and `ip` is not equal `staticipcpe` in table `rm_users`.

I tried the following sql statement but it didn't work.

```
$sqls="select s.ip, s.staticipid from staticip s 
            where s.staticipid='2' and not exists 
            (select u.staticipcpe from rm_users u 
            where u.staticipcpe=s.ip";
```

I have the following message

```
"Warning: mysql_result(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Among other possible problems, you're missing a closing parenthesis:

```
$sqls="select s.ip, s.staticipid from staticip s 
        where s.staticipid='2' and not exists 
        (select u.staticipcpe from rm_users u 
        where u.staticipcpe=s.ip)";
```

Also, [the mysql_* functions are deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli).  Use MySQLi or PDO.

Answer (score 1):

if you query is right you can use NOT IN Clause to achieve your goal

like

```
Select Id
From Test
Where Id Not In( Select Foo From Bar )
```

see for more info

[MySQL "NOT IN" query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519272/mysql-not-in-query)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your database a JOIN may be better over a sub-query (see [Join vs. sub-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-sub-query)), and I also favor backticks ([Importance of backtick around table name in MySQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962859/importance-of-backtick-around-table-name-in-mysql-query)):

```
SELECT `s`.`ip`,`s`.`staticipid`
FROM `staticip` AS `s`
INNER JOIN `rm_users` AS `u`
ON `u`.`staticipcpe`<>`s`.`ip`
WHERE `s`.`staticipid`='2';
```

In plain English:

- SELECT: grab the fields "ip" and "staticipid" from the result
- FROM: the primary table will be "staticip" - alias as "s"
- INNER JOIN: compare the rows in "staticip" with the rows in "rm_users"
- ON (part of INNER JOIN): fetch the rows where "staticipcpe" from "ip" is not listed under the field "staticipcpe" from "rm_users"
- WHERE: filter results such that the value of "staticipid" must be "2"

---

Don't forget to consider indexing the fields `rm_users.staticipcpe`, `staticip.staticipid` (I assume this one is already a PRIMARY KEY), and `staticip.ip`, otherwise you're looking at full table scans, rather than taking advantage of MySQL's b-tree lookup from memory.